# How can I launch a Terminal command in macOS with a universal keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, command-line

In `xfce/gnome/kde` you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up a universal launcher, you just type in the command and it goes.

Is there an equivalent keyboard shortcut for macOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/), a universal launcher that not only supports finding programs and files, but also [running commands directly](https://www.alfredapp.com/help/features/terminal/):

[image]

You can also configure [more complicated workflows](https://www.alfredapp.com/help/workflows/).

Answer (score 3):

Spotlight finds the apps, documents, any other files, but doesn't work with shell commands.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: Is there anyway to run a shell command without opening a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to complete `alt+f2` behaviour, 
check out [Flashlight](https://github.com/w0lfschild/Flashlight) to improve Spotlight, and use the [terminal plugin](http://flashlight.nateparrott.com/plugin/terminal) to improve flashlight.